# How to display loaded data after page refresh in vue, the data is displayed in the console but not in theview

Tags: vue.js

I'm loading notifications from an api using get request, the data is there i can see it in the console but it's not displayed in the view here is my code :

```
    <!-- Header -->
<li class="dropdown-menu-header">
    <div class="dropdown-header d-flex">
        <h4 class="notification-title mb-0 mr-auto">
            Notifications
        </h4>
        <b-badge pill variant="light-primary">
            {{ notifications.length }} New
        </b-badge>
    </div>
</li>

<!-- Notifications -->
<vue-perfect-scrollbar v-once :settings="perfectScrollbarSettings" class="scrollable-container media-list scroll-area" tagname="li">
    <!-- Account Notification -->
    <b-link v-for="notification in notifications" :key="notification.id">
        <b-media>
            <template #aside>
                <b-avatar size="32" :src="require('@/assets/images/avatars/6-small.png')" :text="notification.id" :variant="notification.type" />
            </template>
            <p class="media-heading">
                <span class="font-weight-bolder">
                    {{ notification.data.message }}
                </span>
            </p>
            <small class="notification-text">{{ notification.created_at | formatDate}}</small>
        </b-media>
    </b-link>
</vue-perfect-scrollbar>
```

here is the method :

```
data() {
        return {
            notifications: []
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.getNotifications();
    },
    methods: {
        getNotifications() {
            axios.get(apiHost + '/notification')
                .then((response) => {
                    for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                        this.notifications.push(response.data[i])
                    }
                    console.log(this.notifications)
                })
                .catch(resonse => {
                    console.log(resonse);
                })
        },
    },
```

I just get the length of the array but i can t display the data:

[image]

Comment: no nothing change

Comment: @zerbene you can't use computed for async functions

Answer (score 0):

please try just this:

```js
data() {
        return {
            notifications: []
        }
    },

    async mounted() {
        await this.getNotifications();
    },
    methods: {
        async getNotifications() {
            await axios.get(apiHost + '/notification')
                .then((response) => {
                    this.notifications = response.data
                    }
                })
                .catch(resonse => {
                    console.log(resonse);
                })
        },
    },
```

otherwise please show us the response from the api, if you like mocked of course

Comment: i removed v-once and it worked ! thank you !!